# File/Folder NTFS access permissions for DateCreated property in VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, permissions, server, ntfs

### Outline

The user runs a type of a login script which creates subfolders on a shared drive. In a special case it checks when a specific subfolder was created. The user has full access rights as owner (NTFS permissions) on this item. However, the user has no read permission on the parent folder to prevent looking into other directories. It seems that checking the CreateDate property by `fso.GetFolder(path).DateCreated` is only allowed if the user has also read permission on the parent folder, which seems odd to me.

### Details

The user itself is a member of an AD security group which has limited permissions to parent folder to access the folder for VBS actions.

```
Folder              Name           Permissions             Effect on    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ParentFolder        AD SecGroup    Write, Read Attributes  This, Subfolder & Files
                    Creator-Owner  Full Access             Only Subfolders & Files
  |
  ---->Subfolder    AD SecGroup    Inherited from Parent
                    Creator-Owner  Inherited from Parent
                    Username       Full Access             Only this folder
```

The script can access the subfolder and it exists, but it doesn't get the value of DateCreated property as the following image shows:
[image: Screenshot of field properties on variable]

But if I change the permission for the ParentFolder to this:

```
Folder              Name         Permissions             Effect on    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ParentFolder        AD SecGroup  Write, Read             This, Subfolder & Files
```

I can see the values on DateCreate property
[image: Values are seen]

### Question

How can I get a reliable access to these properties without making the parent folder visible?